# Flutter converting MainAxisSize.max to float

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm building a flutter app, a screen contains a column with four containers. I haven't specified the containers heights as I want them to take up the whole screen. Is there a way to convert the mainAxisSize to a float so that I can set the height of the containers to a quarter of the axis size. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the containers you can use the attribute `heigth`. Then, you can use

`screenHeigth=MediaQuery.of(context).size.heigth` to obtain the heigth size of the phone you are using. Last of all, you can set the Containes' heigth attribute to: `screenHeigth*0.25`

So, each of them are 1/4 of the screen size high!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quick solution I think you are looking for. If not, let me know what to achieve other than this:

**Demo:**
[image]

**Code: **

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Getting Quarter Height of the screen
    double qtrScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height:
                qtrScreen, // Providing the Quarter height to all Containers
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            height: qtrScreen,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: qtrScreen,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            height: qtrScreen,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use expanded and define flex property as you need. You don't need to create values using media query as it makes the code more complex for beginners.